# SublimeText 3: javascript syntax highlighting disappeared

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I had installed Javascript Ultimate plugin, though I did not like any of the themes, so I decided to uninstall the plugin. But for some reason now there is no syntax higlight for javascript files at all. And I can't see javascript in syntax list under `view/syntax`. It is now selected as `Plain Text`. I noticed that when I installed `Javascript Ultimate` plugin, it changed syntax to be called `Javascript Ultimate`. So I guess it removed the standard one and when I uninstalled it was not recreated.

How can I revert javascript syntax back?

Comment: You do know that you can use whatever color scheme you want with whatever syntax you want, right?

Comment: Yes I know. I was just looking for some nice theme, but most of themes are dark which I dont like:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems all I had to do, was to close all the tabs in sublime, not just close sublime itself.